# How can I monitor in/outbound packets through the TCP port in Java?

Tags: java, tcp, port

So as part of a project I'm working on, I am wanting to monitor inbound and outbound packets through a specific port on a single host/device. The program will run in the background and send data to a server where it will eventually be parsed.

I am not wanting to send/receive my own packets but rather monitor the inbound and outbound packets for any anomalies known with TCP, such as a TCP/SYN flood.

I was taking a look around at what might be useful to me, but I am stuck on what would be the best to use to do this as well as how I would start going about this.

What I have found is: [JNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/) and [Pcap4J](https://www.pcap4j.org/)

All help is undeniably appreciated!

Comment: Do you need the data to reach its final destination? or do you just want to intercept it?

Comment: @SteelToe I just need to analyse the packets as they come in and go out

Comment: I can highly reccomend using pcap4J, it has clear documentation and installation instructions and is very very easy to use

Comment: @SteelToe but I don't see, clearly, how I can use it for a single host to monitor just the one port